# How to get user fields in Ember js with has many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have two models User and Recipe. I want to get user fields on recipe page and username in each recipe on user page. I don't know how to do it. In rails i have two has many association between User and Recipe. I added examples of my json arrays that I'm getting from rails.

My json user array

```
user: {
  id: 1,
  name: "ejiqpep",
  email: "ejiqpep@gmail.com",
  recipe_ids: [
    1,
    2
  ],
  box_recipe_ids: [
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

My json recipe array

```
recipe: {
  id: 1,
  title: "recipe01",
  about: "about01",
  ingredients: "ingredients01",
  steps: "steps01",
  visibility_type: true,
  slug: "recipe01",
  user: {
    id: 1,
    name: "ejiqpep",
    email: "ejiqpep@gmail.com",
    recipe_ids: [
      1,
      2
    ],
    box_recipe_ids: [
      1,
      2
    ]
  }
}
```

user.js.coffee

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  email: DS.attr('string')
  recipes: DS.hasMany('App.Recipe')
  box_recipes: DS.hasMany('App.Recipe')
```

recipe.js.coffee

```
App.Recipe = DS.Model.extend
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
  title: DS.attr('string')
```

user.handlebars (I want to get user name in each recipe)

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<p><b>Email:</b> {{email}}</p>

<h3>User recipes</h3>
{{#each recipe in recipes}}
  <div>
    <span>{{recipe.id}}</span>
    <span>!!!I want to show username here!!!</span>
    <span>{{#linkTo recipe recipe}} {{recipe.title}} {{/linkTo}}</span>
  </div>
{{/each}}

<h3>User box_recipes</h3>
{{#each fav in box_recipes}}
  <div>
    <span>{{fav.id}}</span>
    <span>!!!I want to show username here!!!</span>
    <span>{{#linkTo recipe fav}} {{fav.title}} {{/linkTo}}</span>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

recipe.handlebars

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>User {{user.name}}</p>  # I want to show username here!!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don´t know exactly if it works ... but give it a try :

update:

```
{{#each recipes}}
  <div>
    <span>{{id}}</span>
    <span>{{../name}}!!!I want to show username here!!!</span>
    <span>{{#linkTo recipe this}} {{title}} {{/linkTo}}</span>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: i have updated my answer a bit. as i can´t test my suggestion, i don´t know if it is working.

Comment: it works for me! But i can't understand how. Where can i read documentation about this? Why the ../name works? And how i can get it worked on recipe page?

Comment: you can reach the view context outside the each statement with the ../  simmular using 'parentView'. embers documentation is incomplete, if you ask me.  I have found the syntax considering stack overflow as i have the same problem in the past.